# Using ios Simulator for expo react native app

Tags: xcode, macos, react-native, expo

I'm running Mac os catalina on my virtual Machine, and i installed Xcode 10.2 not from the app store, but from the Apple developper portal. when i run the command "npm run ios" on my project directory i got this error:
[image]

knowing i can open ios simulator from xcode 10.2 that i got, is there a solution without downloading xcode 11 from app store cuz is take so so long for the 8.5gb size.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Xcode 10.2 is supported, in general it's best to use the most recent version. However, I would suggest opening up Xcode and trying to start a simulator from there to see if that is working for you.

Comment: what happens if you run `xcrun defaults read com.apple.iphonesimulator CurrentDeviceUDID` in your terminal?

if that works, then try running `xcrun simctl boot <output-of-previous-command>` for example `xcrun simctl boot D0B045E4-91A7-41B3-AFF0-A2BFBA1AF8A1`